# Scroll a div 30px when anchor clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What's the best way to scroll a div with overflow:auto by a certain pixels or certain percentage when clicking an anchor?  The HTML is very simple:

```
<style>
#container{
height:250px;
overflow:auto;
</style>

<div id="container">
<p>Lots of Content</p>
</div>

<a href="#" id="scrolldiv">Scroll Down</a>
```

When I click the anchor above, I want to scroll that div above a certain amount of pixes, say 30px.  I'm hoping jQuery has something built in that makes this simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that purpose I would use [jQuery's animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/):

```
$('#scrolldiv').click(function(){
    $('#container').animate({scrollTop: '+=30'});
});
```

I belive it's got the shortest syntax for this and it looks nice.

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/TpYXL/)

Comment: Thanks, I agree that this is the cleanest and looks the nicest!

Comment: You'll still certainly want to pass the event into your callback and call preventDefault() as the answer below shows.

Comment: Thanks @hackNightly, I will make sure to include this.

Comment: The #scrolldiv should not necessarily be an anchor. I haven't added it for simplicity purposes. And it is working as-is.

Answer (score 6):

```
$('#scrolldiv').click(function(e){
    var current = $('#container').scrollTop();
    $('#container').scrollTop(current + 30);
    e.preventDefault();
});​
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QCGtR/3/)

Comment: Also you could use overflow:hidden (or overflow-y:hidden, overflow-x:auto) so that there are no scrollbars on the #container div. And prefer $("#scrolldiv").live('click',function() {...}); or $("#scrolldiv").on('click',function() {...}); [1.7.x] because it's better.

Comment: @Panagiotis `.live()` is certainly not "better". A) it is depracated B) it does a completely different job. `.live()` delegates your event by binding to the `document` instead of the element itself, which is almost always a bad idea ([from the jquery docs](http://api.jquery.com/on/)): "Avoid excessive use of document or document.body for delegated events on large documents.")

Comment: Thanks, this definitely works, but I'm going with the jquery sample above as it's a bit simpler and has a nicer scroll.

Comment: @Sinetheta true. I wasn't aware of that, because I use one version before the latest. Thanks for pointing it out.